# Download android project from svn cannot using

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

Specs

System:  win7 x64
IDE:     Eclipse
Plug-in: Subclipse

I'm trying to share my android project in an SVN server but only my computer can use it.
When other people downloads my project in their computer, they always have a one named folder.

My Steps:

1. Right click my project
2. Team > Share project
3. Select SVN > Next
4. Select my svn repository link > Use the project name as the folder name > Next and finish
5. Team Synchronizing > Ignore bin, gen, .classpath, .project
6. Submit

Screenshot in my computer when i try to run and build

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkRmO.jpg)

[image]

Screenshot When other people download my project

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zByzL.jpg)

[image]

Why do i always have one similar folder?

Thank you.

Comment: The screenshot2 link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Is seem you are creating a folder name of project on svn repo. and then upload it ,

> just share project on svn without createing 'test1' folder .

Answer (score 0):

When you are downloading the code make sure the path to the project is is

> ....../SourceCode/test1/test1